# Ajax запрос без кодирования url в escape

Tags: ajax, javascript, escape

Посылаю ajax-запрос в одном из параметров url которого есть строка вида

> 16.10.2012 14:56:24

в результате вижу что на сервер ушел запрос в котором эта строка превратилась в

> 16.10.2012+18%3A56%3A24

а нужно что бы получилась строка вида

> 16.10.2012%2014:56:24

а : не должны заменяться вообще.

Как этого добиться ?  Идеально было бы, если бы url вообще не перекодировался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно же послать не в URL, а в data

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'bla_bla_bla',
   data: {
       datetime: '16.10.2012 14:56:24'
   },
   success: function(data) {
      ....
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Делайте [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php) на сервере и забудьте про проблемы.

Comment: К серверу нет доступа! Именно поэтому я и спрашиваю как избежать замены **:** на **%3A**